# When taking the boat from Buenos Aires to Montevideo, then back to Buenos Aires, do the Uruguayan immigration stamp one's passport once or twice?

Tags: passport-stamps, argentina, buenos-aires, uruguay, montevideo

When taking the Buquebus boat service from Buenos Aires to Montevideo, then back from Montevideo to Buenos Aires, do the Uruguayan immigration officers stamp one's passport once (stamp indicating one has exited Uruguay) or twice  (one stamp indicating one has entered Uruguay and one stamp indicating one has exited Uruguay). If that matter, assume the passport holder is a French citizen.

Comment: What practical difference would this make?

Comment: @JonathanReez checking if the immigration officer didn't forget a stamp when entering Uruguay, which could be problematic when exiting Uruguay if it turns out to be required.

Comment: Are you saying that you've already done this, and you believe you are missing a stamp? Or have you not done this yet and you're asking a hypothetical question?

Comment: @GregHewgill I'm planning to take the Buquebus boat service from Buenos Aires to Montevideo, then back from Montevideo to Buenos Aires also by Buquebus.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a ["practical, answerable question based on an actual problem that you face"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @GregHewgill I'm going to take the boat so that's an actual problem. Are you close voting all questions of people planning for their trips?

Comment: Is your question really just  “will my passport be stamped when I arrive in Montevideo?”, or am I missing something?

Comment: @ChrisH no, my question is more specific. If you wish to rephrase it in the way you propose, that'd be "Is your question really just  “will my passport be stamped when I arrive in Montevideo given that I came by boat from Buenos Aires and will come back to Buenos Aires right after Montevideo, also by boat?"

Comment: Why would you not get an entry stamp (but still get an exit stamp) in that case unless they just didn’t do entry stamps in general? I mean, either you’re legally entering Uruguay or you’re not.

Comment: @ChrisH I prefer not to rely on a single immigration officer and instead check myself.

Answer (score 5):

Having done this a couple times I can say that your passport will be stamped twice: once for entry and once for exit. In general, the two immigration checks - Argentinian and Uruguayan - are back to back so the likelihood of missing out on a stamp is fairly low.

Comment: Thanks, interesting, did your take the boat, and how long did you stay in Montevideo?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I took the boat a couple times. I usually stopped in Colonia though.

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing my experience: some friends of mine of myself took the Buquebus boat service from Buenos Aires to Montevideo, then back from Montevideo to Buenos Aires on the same day in early January 2020.

1. None of us received an Uruguayan stamp on their passport upon passing the Uruguayan immigration (we went through 2 Uruguayan immigration officers) at the boarding port in Buenos Aires (RENAPER Buqutheebus), but we did receive an Uruguayan stamp on our Buquebus tickets.
2. On the way back to Buenos Aires, also using the Buquebus boat service, all of us received an Uruguayan stamp on their passport upon passing the Uruguayan immigration (we also went through 2 Uruguayan immigration officers) at the boarding port in Montevideo (Terminal de Buquebus Montevideo in Puerto de Montevideo), and the Uruguayan immigration officers did check whether we had received a entry stamp, which they found on our Buquebus boat tickets. For one of my friends, one of the two Uruguayan immigration officers became agitated when they you couldn't Uruguayan entry stamp (before realizing that the Uruguayan stamp was on the boat ticket).

This means that in my case when taking the boat from Buenos Aires to Montevideo, then back to Buenos Aires, the Uruguayan immigration stamped my passport only once upon exit. The Uruguayan entry stamp was only applied to the boat ticket.